# How to compute the expectation $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$

Tags: probability-theory

Consider a set $\Omega$ of all permutations on the set $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ equipped with the uniform probability measure. For a permutations $\sigma \in \Omega$, let $X(\sigma)$ denote the number of points fixed by $\sigma$. In other words 
$$
X(\sigma)=card\{1\leq j \leq n:\sigma(j)=j\}.
$$

I need to compute $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$, which I cannot do. Please help.

However, I know that $\mathbb{E}[X]=1.$

Comment: How did you find $\mathbb{E}[X]=1$?

Comment: @NateEldredge: For $1\leq j \leq n,$ let's define $X_j$ to be the Bernoulli random variable which takes values $1$ when $\sigma (j)=j.$ Then $\mathbb{E}[X_j]=\mathbb{P}[X_j=1]=1/n.$ But we have that $X=\sum X_j$, hence the claim follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i=1$ to $n$, define random variable $X_i$ by $X_i=1$ if $i$ is left fixed by the randomly chosen permutation, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Then $X=X_1+\cdots +X_n$. It is easy to see that $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{n}$ and therefore $E(X)=n\cdot\frac{1}{n}=1$.

To find $E(X^2)$, expand $(X_1+\cdots +X_n)^2$. We get
$$\sum_1^n X_i^2+2\sum_{i\lt j}X_iX_j.$$
Now use the linearity of expectation. The expectation of $X_i^2$ is easy, since $X_i^2=X_i$. For the expectation of $X_iX_j$, note that $X_iX_j=1$ precisely if $i$ and $j$ are both left fixed. Thus $\Pr(X_iX_j=1)=\Pr(X_i=1)\Pr(X_j=1|X_i=1)$.

Comment: Could you explain the notation in the last statement? What is in the second term of RHS of $\Pr(X_iX_j=1)=\Pr(X_i=1)\Pr(X_j=1|X_i=1)$ ?

Comment: Oh does it mean probability of $X_j=1$ given $X_i=1$? So please let me know if the following is correct: $\Pr(X_iX_j=1)= \Pr(X_i=1)\Pr(X_j=1)\Pr(X_i=1)/\Pr(X_i=1)=1/n^2$. And the number of such terms in the summand should be $n(n-1)/2$. Thus the final expectation should be $$\mathbb{E}[X^2]=1+2.\frac{(n-1)n}{2}.\frac{1}{n^2}=2-\frac{1}{n}.$$ Correct?

Comment: Sorry, I was away. The probability that $X_i=1$ is of course $\frac{1}{n}$. The probability that $X_j=1$ given that $X_i=1$ is $\frac{1}{n-1}$ (same reasoning). So $E(X_iX_j)=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$. The number of terms $X_iX_j$ with $i\lt j$ is $\binom{n}{2}$. Multiply by $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$, then multiply by $2$. We get $1$. So the final answer is $2$.